# copy recursive files and folders but skip parent

Tags: php

```
function copy_directory( $source, $destination ) {
    if ( is_dir( $source ) ) {
        @mkdir( $destination );
        $directory = dir( $source );
        while ( FALSE !== ( $readdirectory = $directory->read() ) ) {
            if ( $readdirectory == '.' || $readdirectory == '..' ) {
                continue;
            }
            $PathDir = $source . '/' . $readdirectory; 
            if ( is_dir( $PathDir ) ) {
                copy_directory( $PathDir, $destination . '/' . $readdirectory );
                continue;
            }
            copy( $PathDir, $destination . '/' . $readdirectory );
        }

        $directory->close();
    }else {
        copy( $source, $destination );
    }
}
```

this is my script for copy whole dirs and files to another destination. But i have small problem

My folders are like:

```
cinch.v2.1.1\cinch\cinch\other folders and files
loopy.v2.1.3\loopy\loopy\other folders and files
musy.v3.1.4\musy\musy\other folders and files
...
```

i need to copy just last (depth 3) cinch, loopy, musy folder with subfolders and files and not whole structure. How to change the script.

and copy structure should looks like this:

```
cinch\other folders and files
loopy\other folders and files
musy\other folders and files
```

I start with

```
if (strpos($readdirectory, '.') === false && strpos($readdirectory, '_') === false) {
```

but this not working as it must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first look for level 3 directories and then copy these to your destination:

```
function copy_directory(...) {
...
}

function copy_depth_dirs($source, $destination $level)
{
    $dir = dir($source);
    while (($entry = $dir->read()) !== FALSE) {
        if ($entry != '.' && $entry != '..' && is_dir($entry)) {
            if ($level == 0) {
                copy_directory($source . '/' . $entry, $destination);
            } else {
                copy_depth_dirs($source . '/' . $entry, $destination, $level - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

copy_depth_dirs('cinch.v2.1.1', $destination, 3);
```

Comment: thank you but can you copy whole part. Becouse if i use if ($last_entry !== FALSE) { copy( $PathDir, $destination . '/' . $readdirectory ); outside of the loop then nothing is copied

Comment: @senzacionale 1. you must of course check for `is_dir()` and 2. use `$last_entry`, because `$readdirectory` is FALSE after while loop.

Comment: hmm mabye you did not understand me correctly. I need to copy last directory as deprth 3 with all sub directories and folder. Sorry if i was not clear enough. I update my question.

Comment: @senzacionale Look at the modified answer.